# $f: [0,1]\rightarrow L^1(\Omega)$ as a (measurable?) function from $[0,1]\times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Given a map from $\big([0,1], \mathcal{B}[0,1], m\big)$ to a Banach space $(X, \|\cdot \|)$. There are **strong measurable** functions (they are the point wise a.e. limit of simple functions) and **weak measurable** functions (for each $u^* \in X^*$, we have $t\mapsto \langle u^*, f(t)\rangle$ is a measurable as a function from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).

I have two questions:

1. Why don't we use the normal measurable definition here? That is a function is measurable if the pre-image of all Borel sets $U\in \mathcal{B}(X)$ are in $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$.
2. Now suppose $X= L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, given a measurable $f:[0,1]\rightarrow L^1$ (either strong, weak or the normal definition), can we say that the function $f(t,\omega)$ is measurable as a function from $[0,1] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with respect to the product sigma on the domain

Comment: (2) is already rather subtle - since elements of $L^1$ are not functions but equivalence classes, it's not even well defined to speak of "the function" $f(t,\omega)$.

Comment: An interesting counterexample to consider is to take $X = \ell^2([0,1])$ (a non-separable Hilbert space).  If $e_t : t \in [0,1]$ is the obvious orthonormal basis, then $f(t) = e_t$ is weakly measurable but not strongly measurable nor Borel.  I think it may be the case that these notions all coincide if $X$ is separable (or maybe if $X^*$ is).